# How do I set UIImage bounds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, bounds

I am having some trouble setting the correct location of the image for a `UIImageView`, which I am adding as a subview to a `UIButton`. I start by creating the button and adding some sublayers:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:bounds];
//add gradient background
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = button.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.5 blue:.5 alpha:1.0].CGColor, (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], nil];
[button.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

//set green background
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.frame = CGRectInset(button.bounds, 5, 5);
layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.55 green:.8 blue:.5 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
[button.layer insertSublayer:layer above:gradient];
```

I then use two methods to set the image. The first (which I use if no image is saved) uses an image resource that is scaled to be the right size, and is part of the app bundle. I set this with the following code:

```
UIImageView *v = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.png"]];
[v setBounds:CGRectInset(button.bounds, 8, 8)];
[button addSubview:v];
```

The trouble comes from when I use an image taken through the camera, and saved to the file system. I am setting this to the background using the following code:

```
//path is an NSString set the the documents location of the image.
UIImageView *v = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
[v setBounds:CGRectInset(button.bounds, 8, 8)];
[v setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[button addSubview:v];
```

The output to the screen now shows the image way offset from where it should be:

[image: example]

What am I doing wrong? How do I correctly scale/fit the image in its parent view? I have tried simply setting the button image, but nothing appeared (perhaps the image was behind the sublayers?).

Comment: why dont you just set image/Background image  of button?

Comment: @LithuT.V, I tried that, and nothing was shown (I believe that is because I am adding `sublayer`s to the button).

Comment: interesting.Can you please add the code of that too?

Comment: @LithuT.V, sure thing. I have made the change.

Comment: Phil, what happens if you replace [button addSubView:v] with [self.view addSubView:v]. I think it might be a frame of reference issue.

Comment: @Spectravideo328, that did change where it was - a little to the left and below the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -`setFrame` method to set the frame of imageview instead of `bounds`

```
[v setFrame:CGRectInset(button.bounds, 8, 8)];
```

Thus the code become

```
UIImageView *v = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
[v setFrame:CGRectInset(button.bounds, 8, 8)];
[v setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[button addSubview:v];
```

Comment: This was it! Thanks. Any advice on when to know if I need to use `setBounds` vs `setFrame`?

Comment: Bounds give you the correct size with origin (0,0) while the Frame gives you all the values the exact from the view it occours in its superview

Comment: `bounds` is the view's coordinates in its own coordinate system, whereas `frame` is the view's coordinates in its parent's coordinate system. The origin of your view is always {0,0} in its own coordinate system.