# UIImageView completely wrong position in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I'm trying to add an UIImageView to a UIView that I created.
However, the position of the image is way too low inside the UIView, even though I set the frames to be equal.
The UIView is called photoView, here is what I did:

```
UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.JPG"]];
imgV.frame = self.photoView.frame;
[self.photoView addSubview:imgV];
```

You can see the result (and the position of photoView in the storyboard) here:
[image]

I have no idea how to fix this, adding

```
imgV.center = self.photoView.center;
imgV.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

doesn't help either.

Comment: Try `imgV.frame = self.photoView.bounds;`.

Comment: Why not add the UIImageView to your storyboard rather than creating one at run-time? You can always set the image property at run-time without having to create a new UIImageView.

Comment: Thanks, that's more elegant (looking) than the solution I just found!

Comment: @lintmachine that's because I have a different number of UIImageViews depending on which button was clicked in the previous ViewController, so I have to add the programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
imgV.frame = self.photoView.bounds;
```

instead of this:

```
imgV.frame = self.photoView.frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the answer, but I'll leave this up here in case anyone else has this question.

The mistake was in the difference between frame and bounds. [This is where I found my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366347/how-do-i-set-uiimage-bounds)

My solution was this:

```
[imgV setFrame:CGRectInset(self.photoView.bounds, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: That's overkill since you have no inset. Just do as I suggested in my comment: `imvv.frame = self.photoView.bounds;`.